# how to check date in range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

In below Code i want to validate date between 02/08/2017 and 05/08/2017 and give us a alert which is Date is not in range

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {

        today = new Date();
        fromdt= new Date("02/08/2017");
        todate=new Date("05/08/2017");

        if( document.myForm.entrydt.value == "" )
           {
             alert( "Please Select Entry Date!" );
             document.myForm.entrydt.focus() ;
             return false;
           }
           else if(!document.myForm.entrydt.value.match(letters3))
          {
          alert("Entry Date: Enter Only Date Format i.e DD/MM/YYYY");
          document.myForm.entrydt.focus() ;
                return false;
            }
            else if (!document.myForm.entrydt.value.today > startdt && !document.myForm.entrydt.value.today < todate)
            {
            alert("Entry Date: Enter Date in Proper Range");
          document.myForm.entrydt.focus() ;
                return false;
            }
        return( true );
        }
        </script>
```

==============================================================================

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" class="form-inline" role="form" name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
        <div id="" class="container" >
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="entrydt">Entry Date</label>=
                                <input class="form-control" style='font-weight:bold;text-transform:uppercase;' id="entrydt" type="text" name="entrydt" style='' placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" value="" size="10">
                            </div>
            </div> 
        </form>
```

Comment: Check the documentation for the `Date` constructor to see the accepted formats. Also remember that `Date` actually includes both date and time, so you'll need to take that into accounting by for the end of your range.

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: Note that `new Date("02/08/2017")` will probably be parsed as 8 Feb 2017. It is not clear from your post wether it should be treated as that or 2 Aug 2017. See marked duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

new Date().getTime() will give time in milliseconds as long value number to compare values

```
var today = new Date().getTime(); // 1501653935994
var from = new Date("02/08/2017").getTime(); // gives 1486492200000
var to = new Date("05/08/2017").getTime();

if(today >= from && today <= to) {
   // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: You are relying on implementation dependent parsing. Use of *getTime* is unnecessary.

Comment: but sir how we write in this sytax is else if (!document.myForm.entrydt.value.today > startdt && !document.myForm.entrydt.value.today < todate)

Comment: @KirankumarGajananGawade then you should convert the input value to a Date before the comparison: `var inputDate = new Date(document.myForm.entrydt.value.today)`. You might want to put a try/catch around that in case the date is not entered in a valid format. In fact, you should give the input `type="date"` and take advantage of the built-in datepicker and validation.

Answer (score 5):

```
new Date().getTime()
```

gives you the timestamp in ms.

```
var today = new Date().getTime();
var from = new Date("02/08/2017").getTime();
var to = new Date("05/08/2017").getTime();
var withinRange = today >= from && today <= to;
```

Comment: you can use an excellent Javascript library : moment.js that provides helpers to compare dates.
Just set a moment var : var mmtDate = moment(new Date());
Set comparison date : var theDate = moment('2017-08-15');
Finally use methods : var before = theDate.isBefore(mmtDate) ? true : false;
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the hint - but why don´t you post it as an answer?

Comment: @FranzDeschler—because posting "use library X" is not an answer and parsing strings without providing the format is error prone.

Comment: but sir how we write in this sytax is else if (!document.myForm.entrydt.value.today > startdt && !document.myForm.entrydt.value.today < todate)

Comment: (!(new Date().getTime() > startdt) && !(new Date().getTime() < todate))